# Keycloak Spring Boot adapter and Ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot application using Keycloak adapter for security and a front-end application using JQuery.

My first question is, do I need to use Keycloak JavaScript adapter in my front-end even though the back-end is already using a Keycloak adapter ?

Let's say that I don't need the JavaScrpt adapter, in that case how can I make the JQuery application continue its execution after the user is login ?

This is my Ajax request:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    try {
        $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
        url : 'https://my-server/my-resource.json',
        data : JSON.stringify(""),
        timeout : 30000, 
        success : function(response) {
            console.log("OK ");
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.srcdoc = response;
            iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(response);
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        },
        error : function(error) {
            console.log("NG " + error);
        }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
    }
});
```

This Ajax request shows the Keycloak login screen, but after the user login how can I get the response of /my-server/my-resource into the JQuery application ?